# D7 - List entries on config form

Tags: 7, forms, hooks

I have what should be a simple question.  I am coding a module that allows the user to add meta and link tags to the  of your HTML page..think of something similar to CSS injector. (I'm sure something like this already exists, but I'm using this as a learning project).  I am able to create the config forms and everything that the admin would need to create a new entry, and I'm able to input new entries and save them to the database.

What I want is below the "new entry" part of the form, I want to list all current entries with "edit" and "delete" links next to each one (every module under the sun has this functionality).  Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Comment: you will probably want to load the data from the database, use https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_table/7 to display it and attach to the form as a new element which would be either #markup or probably even tableselect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on mojzis's comment:

```
// Load your data.
$entries = db_query('SELECT * FROM {my_table}')->fetchAll();

// Prepare a header for your table. The array keys will match up to the key used to input rows in a minute. The values are the column headers.
$header = array(
  'title' => 'Entry title',
  'foo' => 'Bar',
  'op' => 'Operations',
);

// Loop through your data and prepare table rows.
$rows = array();
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
  // Prepare your operation links.
  $op_links = array(
    l('view', 'path/to/entry/' . $entry->id),
    l('edit', 'path/to/entry/' . $entry->id . '/edit', array('query' => drupal_get_destination())),
    l('delete', 'path/to/entry/' . $entry->id . '/delete', array('query' => drupal_get_destination())),
  );

  $rows[] = array(
    'title' => $entry->title,
    'foo' => $entry->bar,
    'op' => implode(' ', $op_links),
  );
}

// Prepare the build
$form['existing_entries'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#rows' => $rows,
  '#empty' => t('No entries have been created.'),
);
```